# Center text with images on the left and right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to create a small navigation using jquery and bootstrap. Im a bit stuck with aligning the images

i have 2 arrow images onto my left and right with the title in the center.

Below is my code

```
<div class="row" style="text-align:center">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_48px-128.png" style="float:left">
   <h2>Heading name or title</h2>
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_48px-128.png">
</div>
```

i did manage to set some margins and paddings and get it working but when the title gets longer the layout breaks also it doesnt work property on responsive views.

Can someone please suggest me a proper way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make the `h2` an inline-block, apply `vertical-align: middle;` to the images and remove the float from the first image:

```css
h2 {
display: inline-block;
}
img {
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_48px-128.png">
   <h2>Heading name or title</h2>
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_48px-128.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have not any other css, This is not what you want, You can use flex:

```
.row {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

And remove the `float: left` from the image.

Also there is no need to `text-align:center` any more.